# How to place default value in to dropdown form field in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm building a post-comment model in one view, one page, something like facebook. I have two forms in my home.html and view.py: new post and new comment. In each post container, there is a new comment form. 
I have a problem because I don't know how to relate comment to post - specifically how to pass post.id to my comment form.

Is it possible to pass my `{{ post.id }}` to my `{{newCommentForm.field }}`? That each comment has a default value of post's id?

My home.html:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="container">
    <a class="user" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>, {{ post.date_posted }}
    <img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" alt="{{ post.author }}"style="width:100%;">
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    <form METHOD="POST" class="new_post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ newCommentForm.content }}
        {{ newCommentForm.post }}
        <button type="submit" name="newCommentSubmit">Add</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def add_coment(self):
        self.date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

views.py

```py
@login_required()
def home(request):
    newPostForm = newPost()
    newCommentForm = newComment()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'newPostSubmit' in request.POST:
            newPostForm = newPost(request.POST, prefix='newpost')
            if newPostForm.is_valid():
                instance = newPostForm.save(commit=False)
                instance.author = request.user
                instance.date_posted = timezone.now()
                instance.save()
            newCommentForm = newComment(prefix='newcomment')
        elif 'newCommentSubmit' in request.POST:
            newCommentForm = newComment(request.POST, prefix='newcomment')
            if newCommentForm.is_valid():
                instance = newCommentForm.save(commit=False)
                instance.author = request.user
                instance.date_posted = timezone.now()
                instance.save()
            newPostForm = newPost(prefix='newpost')
    else:
        newPostForm = newPost(prefix='newpost')
        newCommentForm = newComment(prefix='newcomment')
    context = {
        'newPostForm': newPostForm,
        'newCommentForm': newCommentForm,
        'posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted'),
        'comments': Comment.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html')
```

My model is working now, comments are added, but I need to choose my post (post.id) manually from the default dropdown field witch all posts.
[image: screen]

Comment: Show your Model in models.py

Comment: Done, edited my post.

Comment: If you have the `id` of Post in the request, you should be able to do this: `comment.post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)`. Add your views too, for better insight.

Comment: Done, edited again. And I don't have my ```id``` in the request. Where can I do that?

Comment: Is it possible to add value to ```{{ newCommentForm.post.value }}``` in my home.html somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Add your post to comment like this:

```
if newCommentForm.is_valid():
    instance = newCommentForm.save(commit=False)
    instance.author = request.user
    instance,=.post = request.post
    instance.date_posted = timezone.now()
    instance.save()
```

And send post in request!

Comment: Ok, added, but where to send this post in request? In wich line? And still, how to save ```id``` to this request? On my home.html is multiple posts.

Comment: How does your request object has `user` in it. Add post to request in the same way.

Comment: My ’’’user’’’ is refers to currently logined in user, wich is only one - author of comment.  I have multiple posts in home.html so multiple post ids.

Comment: How does the user know which post is he/she commenting on?

Comment: Add a screenshot of your page for better understanding!

Comment: Ok, screenshot added. Currently I can add new comment when I choose post from dropdown list of all posts (screenshot). My problem is that I want to hide this dropdown list and put there proper post id - id of post where comment form is.

Comment: ```user``` is from models.py ```Profile``` class.